# Safely detect, if function is called from an ISR?

Tags: embedded, cortex-m

I'm developing software for an ARM Cortex M3 (NXP LPC1769) microncontroller. At the moment I'm searching for a mechansim to detect if my function is called within an ISR. I asume that I have to check a register. Based on this information I would like to call difficult functions.

I already checked the reference manual, if there is a register containing the necessary information.

For example I tried to detect if I'm called from an ISR (I used SysTick-ISR) based on the "Interrupt Active Bit Register" (IABR) register. This register should be != 0 if an ISR is active. But the value was 0x00000000. This implies that no interrupt is active. Besides this test I checked the NVIC and SC register in the reference manual searching for a register containing the necessary flag but I didn't found one.

Does anybody know a suitable register / mechanism for my problem?

Comment: Why can't you simply have the ISR calling one function, and the rest of the program a different function?

Comment: Yeah... you have to be very careful when doing this, especially with a tasker.  Still, it's embedded, so good luck!

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps to simplify an RTOS interface.  For example Keil's RL-RTX has separate APIs for interrupt and thread contexts, for example `os_evt_set` and `isr_evt_set`; when writing reusable code, it may not always be possible to predict what contexts it might be used in in the future so you might create a generic `evt_set` wrapper, which can be used anywhere.  Also the OS will behave incorrectly if the wrong API is accidentally called, so run-time selection is safer at the expense of a small overhead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to test the *VECTACTIVE* field of the *Interrupt Control State Register*.

I use the following:

```
//! Test if in interrupt mode
inline bool isInterrupt()
{
    return (SCB->ICSR & SCB_ICSR_VECTACTIVE_Msk) != 0 ;
}
```

SCM and SCB_ICSR_VECTACTIVE_Msk are defined in the CMSIS (core_cm3.h), which I imagine would be included indirectly by your part specific header (lpc17xx.h or similar I guess).  I am using C++, including stdbool.h in C will get you a bool type, or change to an int or typedef of your own.

It is then used thus for example:

```
void somefunction( char ch )
{
    if( isInterrupt() )
    {
        // Do not block if ISR
        send( ch, NO_WAIT ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        send( ch, TIMEOUT ) ;
    }
}
```

If a solution is required that assumes no knowledge of the architecture consider the following:

```
volatile int interrupt_nest_count = 0 ;
#define ENTER_ISR() interrupt_nest_count++
#define EXIT_ISR()  interrupt_nest_count--
#define IN_ISR() (interrupt_nest_count != 0)

void isrA()
{
     ENTER_ISR() ;
     somefunction( 'a' ) ;
     EXIT_ISR() ;
}

void isrB()
{
     ENTER_ISR() ;
     somefunction( 'b' ) ;
     EXIT_ISR() ;
}

void somefunction( char ch )
{
    if( IN_ISR() )
    {
        // Do not block if ISR
        send( ch, NO_WAIT ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        send( ch, TIMEOUT ) ;
    }
}
```

However the question refers to *safely* detecting the interrupt context, and this relies on the enter/exit macros being added to *all* ISRs.

Comment: I would make 'interrupt_nest_count' volatile

Comment: @Ibrahim : So would I; it only took 5 years for someone to notice!  Thanks.  Hopefully anyone to whom this is useful used the first method.

Comment: C doesn't guarantee atomicity for `i++` by default, even if `i` is volatile.

Comment: @Groo : Good point - an exercise for the reader.  There may be good reasons for relying on implementation/architecture dependent behaviour rather the language defined behaviour.  To minimise interrupt latency for example.  It was a kernel on an idea.

Comment: I consider your first example to be the best one (checking a certain platform-dependent flag), even if it's not "portable". Embedded code will need a hardware abstraction layer anyway, there is no other way to make it portable to a different platform. Especially since this answer is exactly what OP asked, for that specific architecture.

Comment: @Groo : I think I say as much in the answer.  It was a long time ago - perhaps I would omit the second if answering today.

Answer (score 16):

After some discussion and more searching I found the right register:
Interrupt Program Status Register: The IPSR contains the exception type number of
the current Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). See the register summary in Table 626 for
its attributes.

If a function isn't called from an isr the value of the register is IPSR == 0

Comment: Yes, IPSR is the register I've used for this purpose in the past.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest method is to pass the context as a parameter to the function. It is also platform independent.

```
typedef enum _context {
    normal_context = 0,
    isr_context = 1
} context;
```

Call to the function from ISR:

```
func(param1, param2, isr_context);
```

Call to the function from normal code:

```
func(param1, param2, normal_context);
```

If the ISR code is not under your control and you are just passing a function pointer, then just use two different wrapper functions. One that passes isr_context and another that passes normal_context as a parameter to the function.

Comment: I think the "simplest method" is in fact to interrogate the processor status.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is probably to make two different functions: one that is called from the ISR and another that is called from the rest of the program.

If that isn't an option, then you could determine the caller with pure standard C, no registers needed:

```c
inline void my_func (const char* caller);

static void isr (void)
{
  my_func(__func__);
}


inline void my_func (const char* caller)
{
  if(strcmp(caller, "isr")==0)
  {
    // was called from isr
  }
  else
  {
    // called from elsewhere
  }
}
```

If you give your ISRs smart names, the above code will be quick enough to run from an isr.

Comment: The processor "knows" when it is an interrupt context.  This is an unnecessary, inefficient and error prone method.

Comment: That's one opinion, but it's a debatable one.  Blindly calling the same code and expecting it to behave differently based on deep knowledge of the hardware details isn't the kind of practice everyone would consider proper either.  It all depends on what you are trying to do and what concerns are paramount.  It's also possible to imagine situations where code is in an interrupt context from the perspective of a scheduler, but no longer in one as far as the hardware is concerned.

Comment: @Clifford No, a processor does not know that. An ARM Cortex M3 knows that. It seems that the OP is writing some sort of library which is independent of the hardware. This code is portable. It is _not_ inefficient, it can be optimized further into something that the compiler can evaluate at compile time and then discard. With some tiny modification, you can have the pre-processor output as  `if('i' == 'i' && 's' == 's' && 'r' == 'r' && '\0' == '\0')`. Which of course any half-decent compiler will optimize away at compile time. How this would be error prone is beyond me, care to explain?

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  As in my answer you write a wrapper function and implement it for all the architectures your code runs on,  A hardware abstraction layer such as that *is* a portable solution.

Comment: @Lundin I beg to differ - the question is very specific about a Cortex M3 specific solution. Portability is better served by a hardware abstraction wrapper.  I am wondering what hardware you might come across that has no means of determining an interrupt context.  Error prone because it relies on the caller passing the correct information.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the function in my answer has a sister function called isThread() - this returns true when in a thread context, but false when either the scheduler is not started or in an ISR.  Between then it covers most context scenarios and I have ported it between several RTOS and architectures.

Comment: @Clifford I started my answer with questioning how it would make sense to have such a feature inside a separate function in the first place, and why the code simply can't be placed inside ISR. The only sane reason for not doing so, is when implementing some sort of "thread-safe" library.

Comment: @Clifford Most MCUs only have a feature to determine whether a specific interrupt was triggered or not. They implement a global interrupt mask, which means that all interrupts are enabled/disabled. Since this mask is automatically set upon entering an ISR, it may be used to determine whether an interrupt in running or not. But since the mask typically resides inside a condition code register, you cannot read it with C code, you will need inline assembler, which is non-portable.

Comment: @Clifford "Error prone because it relies on the caller passing the correct information" Unlike which other function with parameters ever made in any context? You can't be serious. Should we ban the use of functions in all programming then, since they are all "unsafe"?

Comment: @Lundin I'll leave it at that, you are starting to wear.  Suffice it to say, IMO this is a rather inelegant solution to a simple problem. You have added a `strcmp()` to something that requires only a bit test - and in an ISR that might be critical.

Comment: Interesting argument to read when I find this thread because I have the same question as OP. I'll have to wholeheartedly side with @Clifford on this one. In my case, I have some functions that should never execute in an interrupt context. I tell myself to never call them in an interrupt context, I can put in comments with such warnings, etc. However, I still do not trust myself to remember that 2 months from now, and I definitely do not trust anyone who may change the code after me to never miss that warning in the comments. Therefore, I will test IPSR and be done with it.

Comment: This is a good example of the constant philosophical battle between embedded people and high-level CS people who don't know when to stop. IMO, a lot of modern CS education focuses a lot on making things look elegant even if that leaves no hope for said thing to actually *BE* elegant. Those who fall for this way of thinking miss out on a lot of fun in life, and end up being very irritating to the local EE majors who prioritize the machine running well over the code looking pretty. I constantly see this generic-OOP-panacea mentality harm projects. Don't buy into it so wholeheartedly.

Comment: @Dmitri What are you babbling about? There's nothing particularly OOP here on either side of these (old) arguments. And beside that, good OOP and good realtime characteristics are not mutually exclusive. That being said, who are the high-level CS people here? Everyone who were involved in this debate seem to be embedded/realtime systems veterans...

Comment: @Lundin Yep... Read first post, ignore the second. Looking back at it, too much work that day, wasn't thinking completely straight (and possibly commenting on personal frustrations of the day, ahem...). I thought (and still think) that bit of code is overcomplicating things unnecessarily in the given situation sinply for the sake of being more generic, as is characteristic of some in the high-level CS crowd, hence the association. Had the OP not specified a CPU or said it needs to be generic, then I wouldn't disagree with you.